# npm run deploy script not giving link

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, web-hosting

I keep getting this error message when I try to use npm run deploy.

However, I do seem to have a deploy script in my package.json file

I am also cded into the package.json directory

I have tried turning github pages on but when I go to the link it gives me a 404 error

As a result I have turned off github pages

Extended Error message (npm debug log):

```
14 verbose lifecycle myportfoliosite@0.1.0~deploy: CWD: C:\Users\Ali Haider\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\myportfoliosite\myportfoliosite
15 silly lifecycle myportfoliosite@0.1.0~deploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gh-pages -d build' ]
16 silly lifecycle myportfoliosite@0.1.0~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle myportfoliosite@0.1.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
18 verbose stack Error: myportfoliosite@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
19 verbose pkgid myportfoliosite@0.1.0
20 verbose cwd C:\Users\Ali Haider\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\myportfoliosite\myportfoliosite
21 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
22 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy"
23 verbose node v10.16.0
24 verbose npm  v6.9.0
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error myportfoliosite@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the myportfoliosite@0.1.0 deploy script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 1, true ]



File sizes after gzip:

  73.02 KB  build\static\js\2.f6e5e996.chunk.js
  19.04 KB  build\static\css\2.b1979bb4.chunk.css
  797 B     build\static\js\runtime~main.4f085a03.js
  152 B     build\static\js\main.a0a932a3.chunk.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /InquisitiveDev2016/ReactDeveloperPortfolio/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:
```

Error appearing in terminal:

```
> myportfoliosite@0.1.0 deploy C:\Users\Ali Haider\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\myportfoliosite\myportfoliosite
> gh-pages -d build

'gh-pages' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myportfoliosite@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myportfoliosite@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ali Haider\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-29T02_08_30_836Z-debug.log
```

Here is my repository: https://github.com/InquisitiveDev2016/ReactDeveloperPortfolio

My json folder:

```
{
     "name": "myportfoliosite",
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "private": true,
     "homepage": "https://github.com/InquisitiveDev2016/ReactDeveloperPortfolio",
     "dependencies": {
       "react": "^16.8.6",
       "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
       "react-mdl": "^1.11.0",
       "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
       "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "start": "react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test",
       "predeploy": "npm run build",
       "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
     },
     "eslintConfig": {
       "extends": "react-app"
     },
     "browserslist": {
       "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all"
       ],
       "development": [
         "last 1 chrome version",
         "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version"
       ]
}
}
```

Comment: I cloned your repo to test and worked for me, but after I've fixed the syntax in the package.json file. The package.json you provided in your question is different from the one in the repo. You have an extra bracket before "browserlist".

Are you sure you are running `npm run deploy` from within a folder where package.json has that script?

Comment: Open `C:\Users\Ab\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\myportfoliosite\package.json`, and see if its different

Comment: Can you try npm --prefix /path/to/project run deploy

Comment: `gh-pages` should be included in devDependencies of package.json. Try `npm install gh-pages --save-dev` to do it.

Comment: @Samuel I tried the command and now I do see a gtihub pages branch option on my repository so thanks a lot! I enabled GitHub pages with the gh pages branch now and received this link: https://inquisitivedev2016.github.io/ReactDeveloperPortfolio/                                     Previously the link wasn't working but now it does. However, it is still not displaying the actual site I created

Answer (score 0):

check your folder tree there you might find build folder there delete catch folder and save then run npm run deploy

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32753718)